# Software center download won't stop/cancel

Tags: software-center

This feels like a dumb question but I'm fairly new to ubuntu/linux and I don't know what to do.

I tried downloading something in Ubuntu software centre (dropbox I believe) a while ago. It never got anywhere so I attempted to cancel it. Well it wont actually cancel or go away from the progress queue. Its preventing me from installing anything from the software centre or the terminal via sudo apt-get. Its also preventing me from uninstalling software centre since uninstalling anything just gets added to the queue.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Beyond the obvious restarting the computer I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: A cool Ubuntu trick: Press *Shift* and *PrintScreen* on your keyboard at the same time. You'll be able to select a part of your screen, which will be used for a screenshot. Better than taking an actual photo of your screen.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the current content of `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/termn.log`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can kill the process that using the software center

usually use these commands:

```
sudo killall apt-get dpkg software-center
```